# Using R, How can I flag sequential duplicate values in a single column of a dataframe

Tags: r, duplicates

This is my first post and I'm new to programming and R.

I'm trying to create a new column to mark or flag sequentially duplicated values in a separate column.

df <-  c(2,2,2,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,2,3,7,7,7))

Using the duplicated function returns the following:

data.frame(value = df, flag = duplicated(df))

```
   value  flag  
1      2  FALSE  
2      2  TRUE  
3      2  TRUE  
4      2  TRUE  
5      3  FALSE  
6      4  FALSE  
7      3  TRUE  
8      4  TRUE  
9      3  TRUE  
10     4  TRUE  
11     2  TRUE  
12     3  TRUE  
13     7  FALSE  
14     7  TRUE  
15     7  TRUE
```

What I'd like is:

```
   value  flag  
1      2  TRUE  
2      2  TRUE  
3      2  TRUE  
4      2  TRUE  
5      3  FALSE  
6      4  FALSE  
7      3  FALSE  
8      4  FALSE  
9      3  FALSE  
10     4  FALSE  
11     2  FALSE  
12     3  FALSE  
13     7  TRUE    
14     7  TRUE    
15     7  TRUE
```

My data set has over 2 million observations, so ideally the solution would be efficient.

Thank you ,
John

Comment: Since you are relatively new here you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and the [**faq**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about how SO works. StackOverflow is made much more valuable to everyone if when you receive an answer that solves your problem, you accept it by clicking the little check mark or upvote a useful answer. You are under absolutely no obligation to do either, but it is a great way to "give back" to the site if an answer did in fact solve your problem and helps keep the site free of unanswered questions that have been answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rle` will get you what you are after in combination with `rep`

```
rl <- rle( df )
rep( rl$lengths != 1 , times = rl$lengths )
#  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [15]  TRUE
```

And I believe `rle` is fairly efficient.

Timing (MBP late 2008) on a 2e6 length vector:

```
system.time({ rl <- rle( df )
res <- rep( rl$lengths != 1 , times = rl$lengths )
 })
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.449   0.106   0.559
```

Comment: Hah! I had started thinking about this problem with `rle` and then I saw your answer and switched. And now you've switched to `rle`. :)

Comment: I guess you realized before me that the older approach was not going anywhere. Upvote.

Comment: @asb lol, that often happens to me!! Thanks for the upvote :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have more than 2 millions I recommand you really to switch to `data.table`. Here My solution using `rle` similar to @Simon one, I just write its `data.table` version. I believe that is not always obvious especially for beginners(like me under data.table).

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1234)
dd <- sample(1:20, 2e+06, rep = TRUE)
DT <- data.table(dd)
system.time(DT[, `:=`(grp2, {
                            dd.rle = rle(dd)  ## store rle to not call it twice
                            rep(dd.rle$lengths > 1, times = dd.rle$lengths)
             })])
##    user  system elapsed 
##    1.17    0.06    1.28
##    user  system elapsed  <- rle twice
##    1.69    0.11    1.86

##        dd  grp2
## 1e+00:  3 FALSE
## 2e+00: 13  TRUE
## 3e+00: 13  TRUE
## 4e+00: 13  TRUE
## 5e+00: 18 FALSE
##    ---         
## 2e+06:  6 FALSE
## 2e+06:  5 FALSE
## 2e+06:  4 FALSE
## 2e+06: 10 FALSE
## 2e+06: 13 FALSE
```

Comment: +1 I was going to do this, honest! I just decided it would take me too long to figure out - I still SUCK at `data.table` Nice work.

Comment: You could perhaps be even quicker by not using `rle` twice?